# Notification for certain amount of time

Tags: c#

I have notification service and I would like to display the notification for the time these operations are running. Now the notification appears and then after few seconds is gone. I have tried while loop and of course also google but to be honest I am not sure how to search. I have tried.. notification service display for certain amount of time seconds# Set time out to an operation.. Can you help please ..even just suggestion for how to google it would help :

```cs
protected async void DownloadArticle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DownloadArticleMain();
}


private async Task<bool> DownloadArticleMain()
{
    this.IsBusy = true;
    while(IsBusy == true)
    {
        NotificationService.ShowToast(Resx.AppResources.A_ToastSavingOne);

        await DownloadAndSetArticleDetailAsync(_currentArticle.Id);
        await Task.Run(() => { DeleteFilesInDirectoryAndCreateNewDirectory(); });
        await DownloadHeaderMp3Async();
        await DownloadSentencesMp3Async();
        await Task.Run(() => { SerializeArticleDetailToXml(); });
        await DownloadWordsMp3Async();
        await DownloadArticleImageAsync();

        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
public class NotificationService
{
    public static void ShowToast(string message, NotificationLength length = NotificationLength.Long)
    {
        {
            var toastLength = ToastLength.Long;
            switch (length)
            {
                case NotificationLength.Short:
                    toastLength = ToastLength.Short;
                    break;
            }

            var toast = Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, message, toastLength);
            toast.SetGravity(Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center, 0, 0);
            toast.Show();

        }
    }
}
    
public enum NotificationLength
{
    Long,
    Short
}
```

Comment: why can't you have another method `NotificationService.HideToast(Resx.AppResources.A_ToastSavingOne);` and call it when all your operations are complete

Comment: i dont need that i need to keep the notification up until the operations is running

Comment: Is there a way to determine your operations are still running?

Comment: i am not sure, how can i find out